# How do I store the default imageicon path on jlabel in my database

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, nullpointerexception

I am working on a registration form in Java that has a label for displaying the image uploaded from the `JFileChooser`.

My problem is that I want to use the absolute path of the default image on the `jlable` if the user doesn't click the button for uploading the image(because that's the only point the filechooser comes to play).

But even when I use `getImageIcon` I still get-

> null pointer exception.

This is probably because I store the path returned by the `jfilechooser` in an input stream variable before storing it in a blob field in MySQL and I don't know how to go about this.

I am using `net-beans` as my IDE. Your help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This is the code extract

String imgPath = new ImageIcon(ApplicationClass.class.getResource("defaultImg.png")).toString();
imgPath = imgPath.replace("/", "\");

InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(imgPath));

This is the implementing method

```
private void registerBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

        try{
            String userName  = "root";
            String passWord = "";
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aofm_db";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,passWord);         

                InputStream is = null;
                if(imgPath.isEmpty() || imgPath ==null){
                    is = MainActivity.class.getResourceAsStream("defaultImg.png");
                }else{
                    is = new FileInputStream(new File(imgPath));
                }
                //InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(imgPath));
                PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into register(fname,mname,lname,dob,phone,area,status,image) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                pstmt.setString(1, fnameFld.getText());
                pstmt.setString(2, mNameFld.getText());
                pstmt.setString(3, lNameFld.getText());
                pstmt.setString(4,((JTextField)dobChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
                pstmt.setString(5, phoneFld.getText());
                pstmt.setString(6, areaFld.getText());
                pstmt.setString(7, (String) statusCombo.getSelectedItem());
                pstmt.setBlob(8, is);
                pstmt.executeUpdate();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "New member successfully added", "Registration Message", 1);
                fnameFld.setText("");
                mNameFld.setText("");
                lNameFld.setText("");
                dobChooser.setDate(null);
                phoneFld.setText("");
                areaFld.setText("");
                statusCombo.setSelectedItem("");
                imageLbl.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("defaultImg.png")));
                imgPath = null;

          }catch(Exception e){
                System.err.println(e);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registration Error. Make sure to upload an image. Contact developer if problem persists afterwards "+e, "Registration Message", 0);
          }

    }

//When user uploads an image
private void uploadBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {      
        JFileChooser filechooser = new JFileChooser();

        filechooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("*.IMAGE","jpg","gif","png");
        filechooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
        filechooser.setDialogTitle("Choose an image");
        filechooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        int returnval = filechooser.showOpenDialog(this);
        if(returnval==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {    File file = filechooser.getSelectedFile();
             String path=file.getAbsolutePath();
             imageLbl.setIcon(ResizeImage(path));
             imgPath = path;
             System.err.println("path "+path);


        }
    }
```

Comment: The output console of the error in java.lang.NullPointerException.  Which is because of this line of code
 InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(imgPath));
The problem is that I don't know how to pass the default image path in my application to the InputStream variable when the user doesn't upload an image before submitting the form.

Comment: Is the default image a file?  If it is, why not just assign `imgPath` the path to the default image file, if imgPath is null?

Comment: That's what I want to do but I can't because the image file is in my netbeans project . Am considering this because I want the image file to be seen even on a different pc after the project is packaged without having to copy the image file on that pc as well. Thank you

Comment: A file inside your project should always be read using [Class.getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) and never as a regular file.  For instance, `new ImageIcon(MyApplication.class.getResource("images/defaultImage.png"))`  Class.getResource is location independent:  it will work regardless of the directory where your project resides, and it will work when you package your program as a .jar file.

Comment: I get this error when I use your approach java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\java_projects\AOFM_Manager\build\classes\aofm_manager\defaultImg.png (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect) @VGR

Comment: A URL is not a file.  Using toString() will not make it a valid file.  Why are you insisting on using FileInputStream, when you already have an ImageIcon?  What is your real goal here?  Do you want an image, or do you just want an InputStream?

Comment: @VGR  thanks for your assistance I really appreciate the effort. The goal is to store the ImageIcon in a an inputstream variable so that I can save it in my database blob field because that's what the program does when the user uploads an image. I want the program to use the default image when the user doesn't upload instead of returning a null pointer exception but it looks like am not doing it right.

Comment: Do not use ImageIcon or Image at all, if you want to store it in a database.  For the default image, just use [Class.getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-).  Note the **AsStream** part in the method name.  You should not load it into an ImageIcon;  you *already have* an InputStream.  Similarly, for storing image files, you should use the initial InputStream and save the raw bytes in the database, rather than using ImageIcon.

Comment: From your last comment this how I am implementing  your solution
 InputStream is = null;
                if(imgPath.isEmpty() || imgPath ==null){
                    is = MainActivity.class.getResourceAsStream("defaultImg.png");
                }else{
                    is = new FileInputStream(new File(imgPath));
                }
The if part is the most important now but I still get the same filenotfound exception. Pardon me if I have misinterpreted your code @VGR

Comment: Does the stack trace indicate that the FileNotFoundException occurred in the call to `new FileInputStream`?  If so, did you verify that imgPath is a path that actually exists?

Comment: Yes the file exists because after every successful registration I run this code and I get no errors. imageLbl.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("defaultImg.png")));

Comment: Instead of System.err.println(e), use `e.printStackTrace();`.  That will tell you exactly which line of code is causing the error.  Although, it looks like the only line which could possibly generate a FileNotFoundException is `new FileInputStream`.  Try replacing it with `is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(imgPath));`.  That will yield a much more informative exception.  (java.io.File is obsolete and was replaced years ago by the java.nio.file package.)

Comment: @VGR you are right I am now getting a more detailed error message. This is what is causing the problem java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 4: file:/C:/java_projects/AOFM_Manager/build/classes/aofm_manager/defaultImg.png

Comment: Now we’re getting somewhere. That’s not a file path at all—it’s a URL.  Edit your question and show the code that sets the value of `imgPath`.

Comment: @VGR the code  works when I comment the if block and just set InputStream is = MainActivity.class.getResourceAsStream("defaultImg.png"); but when I uncomment I get a null pointer exception. I have included the method for implementing the imgPath

Comment: So, you’re *always* using "defaultImg.png"?  Is imgPath ever set to anything other than "defaultImg.png"?  I see no code which sets it to anything else.

Comment: Everything is working fine now @VGR. Thanks for the help. I replaced the if block with this if(imgPath !=null && !imgPath.isEmpty()){
                    is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(imgPath));
                }

Comment: In that case, I leave you with this advice.  Do not, under any circumstances, use the toString() method of ImageIcon for anything other than debugging, since [it does not guarantee the format of the string it returns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#toString--).  Really, you should not be using ImageIcon at all—you just need bytes, not a renderable image.  Get your InputStream [directly from the URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream--).